# How to write flipped \in?

Tags: symbols

How to write a horizontally flipped version of `\in` in mathematics mode?

Google gives me `\reflectbox` and something like that, but I feel that there is a more straightforward way to write it since the need to use it comes naturally in mathematical texts.

Comment: `\ni`. For future reference, see http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Also for future reference, see [how to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: Also related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIV4poUZAQo `:)`